# Lisp: Can't detect empty list (list nil)?

Tags: lisp

I am trying to write a simple program to detect a list is empty `(list nil)` or not. However, when I run the following piece of code:

```
(defvar emptyList (list nil))
(if (not emptyList)
    (print "emptyList is empty.")
)
```

Nothing is printed, meaning that `(not emptyList)` evaluated to `false`. This seems strange, since I though that `(not emptyList)` is the correct way to determine whether `emptyList` is empty or not?

Comment: `emptyList` isn't an empty list. It's a list with one element, that element is `nil`.

Comment: `(list nil)` is not the same as `nil`, just as `(list 0)` is not the same as `0`.

Comment: FYI, the function normally used to test for an empty list is `null`. It's equivalent to `not`, but `not` is conventionally used to test boolean values rather than lists.